# store array of uris to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have array of uri's. i show them using while loop in image view. but i want to store in Sqlite so that if no internet available i can use that array of uri later on to show in Imageview.

I have not tried any code please consider my apology. though i have tried simple example of storing in Sqlite.

I tried this

```
 Iterator<Uri> iterator = mMedia.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                uri = iterator.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a table having id and uris as column and add more column as per your requirement. Further do CRUD(Create Read Update Delete) operation.

```
for(String uri : arrUri)
{
 //insert every uri you have in array to db 
}
```

Comment: sir i don't know how much images uri i have in that array of uri so can you elaborate.

Comment: Doesn't matter on no. of  images. Simply insert them one by one (row by row).  Just get an array iterate it and insert in db on every iteration.

Comment: listen i dont know number of images so how am i suppose to know that how much column or row i needed..can you provide me some code..

Comment: dude, do you have any idea of SQL. You just need to insert every new uri in a row.

Comment: i get your code.but how much column do i need to create to store images uri. if i dont know the count

Comment: i am just new in Sqlite can you please write more code that how many column do i need or something please

Comment: I already mentioned, i can't provide you the code. That you have to search on your on. I can only help you , if you stuck somewhere .

Comment: i understand sir its been three days..so if you please help me this time it would be great..from next time i will search for more time..but this time is very important..please